# How to Automatically call an Angular $http request on a regular interval

Tags: angularjs

I have a MVC web application with an Angular front end. I want the View to automatically update it's contents by triggering a function that makes an Angular $http request on a set interval.

I'm pretty sure I have all the pieces needed to make this work but I can't seem to fit them together.

This is what I'm currently trying,

Angular:

```
app.controller("processModel", function ($scope, $http, $interval) {

    $scope.GetData = function () {
        $interval($scope.LoadData, 3000);
    }

    $scope.LoadData = function() {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'Home/DataRefresh'
        }).then(function success(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
        }, function error(errResponse) {
            alert("ERROR!");
        });
    };  
});
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom:0; padding-top:10px;" ng-init="GetData()">

    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">

        <td>{{item.info}}</td>

    </tr>

<div>
```

This code either fires once on the page-load after waiting 3 second and then stops (Home/DataRefresh never gets hit again) OR it does hit every 3 seconds and throws the generic ERROR every time.

Which one of these two behaviors it expresses is inconsistent and I can't figure out why it does which.

EDIT: So I have changed the angular to this and added an alert debugging statement.

```
app.controller("processModel", function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
    $scope.LoadData = function() {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'Home/REIDataRefresh'
        }).then(function success(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
            alert("Got into the success response");
        }, function error(errResponse) {
            alert("data " + errResponse.data + " status " + errResponse.status + " headers " + errResponse.headers + "config " + errResponse.config + " statusText " + errResponse + " xhrStat " + errResponse.xhrStatus);
        });
    };  

    $interval($scope.LoadData, 3000);
});
```

Very strangely, it *does* get to that `alert("Got into the success response");` every 3 seconds, but the Action Method only gets hit the first time. I don't understand why this would be the case.

Comment: I would suggest not using `ng-init` to trigger the interval but rather directly call `$interval($scope.LoadData, 3000);` from inside the controller. As the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) suggests, ng-init usage should be restricted to very specific use cases.

Comment: As for the request always failing, first check you can call it manually and you don't have any error in the console. And check the network inspector to see what is the error code of the request. It might give you some hints.

Comment: Yeah when I manually call it once (just removing the $interval wrapper) it works consistently and loads the data find.

I've tried putting $interval in a bunch of different places and tried invoking the controller in a few different ways but I can never get it to just loop and make the call repeatedly.

How can I trigger that interval from the HTML without ever binding it to some directive?

Comment: The error is generic only because you have ignored the `errResponse` object which will give you lots of clues why it's not working. For that many requests would be better for server load to use websockets

Comment: @charlietfl I expanded the various parts of the error and didn't get anything particularly useful. in fact, I have figured out how to reliably trigger the call the LoadData on an interval, but for some reason the Action Method only gets hit the first time even though all subsequent intervals it makes it into that "success return" branch of that $http call. OP Updated.

Comment: Might be being cached. Look in $http docs for cache settings or add `params:{'_': +new Date()}` as a cache buster for the url to always be unique

Comment: If error object being logged at least look at status. It is most likely not 200

Comment: Adding the `params:{'_': +new Date()}` did it!! Now I just need to figure out how to refresh the div when the call returns new data, but thats a whole other question.

Comment: So essentially the whole issue was caching it sounds like